# jQuery + Simple Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, modal-dialog

I have a jQuery Model windows which contains a form.

On creating of the page, I'm able to see the fields although in my dialog, i have set autoOpen to false.

All the forms are in a div.

a sample of my dialog looks like this:

```
$("#dialog-form").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                height: 460,
                width: 750,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    'Create Map': function() {
                        document.registerFrm.submit();
                    },
                    Cancel: function() {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                },
                close: function() {
                    allFields.val('').removeClass('ui-state-error');
                }
            });
```

Any way to resolve, I don't want the form fields to be visible on load/creation of the page.

Comment: Does the div have an id of dialog-form?

Comment: Yes James, the dialog-form is the name of the id in the div

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to hide it initially vis CSS, like this:

```
#dialog-form { display: none; }
```

The opening of the dialog will cause it to display...this is what the authors of the dialog widget expect you to do :)

Alternatively, hide the div containing all the forms...whatever you don't want hidden just `display:none` on that wrapper, the dialog will grab and show that or whatever's in it and show it accordingly (just don't do the `display` on every child, only the wrapper), like this:

```
<div style="display: none;">
  <div id="dialog-form">fields here</div>
  <div id="dialog-form2">fields here</div>
</div>
```

Or just this:

```
<div id="dialog-form" style="display: none;">
  fields here
</div>
```

Comment: Nice, even thought I know abt the style, I wasn't aware of such stuff. Thanks!!